# Fonts issue in game maker 1.2

Tags: fonts, game-maker, gml

im trying to use more than one font in GM, but when using draw_set_font in a draw event both of my drawed fonts becomes the same, even though i'm using draw_set_font in two different objects.Please, how can i do to solve this?

Here is the first object, called hud:

```
if(global.dead == false){
    //Draw health bar
    draw_sprite(spr_hearts, global.hp, 10,10)
    //Set score
    //draw_set_color(c_white)
    //draw_set_font(fnt_main)
} else {
    draw_text((room_width/2) - 30,room_height/2-30 , "GAME")
    draw_text((room_width/2) - 25,room_height/2 , "OVER")
}
```

Here is the second, called obj_score:

```
draw_set_color(c_white)
draw_set_font(fnt_score)
draw_text(140,10,"SCORE : " + string(global.score))
```

Comment: show the code of the objects (draw event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`draw_set_font()`, `draw_set_colour()`, etc. functions change the global state of the graphics pipeline. It's not independent for every object. So, object `hud` should be like:

```
if !global.dead
{
    // Draw health bar
    draw_sprite(spr_hearts, global.hp, 10, 10);
}
else
{
    draw_set_color(c_white); 
    draw_set_font(fnt_main);
    draw_set_halign(fa_center);
    draw_set_valign(fa_middle);
    draw_text(room_width div 2, room_height div 2, "GAME#OVER"); // or "GAME\nOVER" for GMS2
}
```

And obj_score:

```
draw_set_color(c_white);
draw_set_font(fnt_score);
draw_set_halign(fa_left);
draw_set_valign(fa_top);
draw_text(140, 10, "SCORE : " + string(global.score));
```

or if you want it together:

```
draw_set_color(c_white); 
draw_set_font(fnt_score);
draw_set_halign(fa_left);
draw_set_valign(fa_top);
draw_text(140, 10, "SCORE : " + string(global.score));

draw_set_font(fnt_main);
draw_set_halign(fa_center);
draw_set_valign(fa_middle);
draw_text(room_width div 2, room_height div 2, "GAME#OVER");
```